# Maximum RF power for microstrip

Tags: power, rf, microstrip

Microstrip line have couple parameters that we can change. It's track width (W), copper thickness (t) & substrate thickness (h).
The question is "How much RF power we can transfer by this microstrip?"

For example, we've got RO4350B and 20 GHz. W = 0.54 mm. I can change h or t and it will change W for 50 ohm line. How many power (in watts) we can use with defined frequency, track thickness and sub thickness?

[image: Microstrip characteristics on 20GHz freq]

Comment: Hi! So, what are your thoughts so far on what limits the power? (this feels *a lot* like a learning assignment, and you've not really described what you want to learn and what you already know :) )

Comment: it seems to me that the power limiter is the cross-section of the strip. The cross section, in turn, depends on the sub thickness and material (given the fact that we work in the high frequency range). It has been found from experience that a 1mm wide strip cannot transmit 800 watts. It evaporates :D
Also found 2 formula's that gave me 23 MW and 7.77*10^(-10) W
Probably it isn't right :D

Comment: Welcome! Is this homework?

Comment: no, this is a task at work. I want to understand the maximum permissible constant RF power on a strip of a certain size to use in in antenna application's.

Comment: @Desinus astute observation! So, we have identified two limiting factors here: 1. heat 2. ability to contain energy in the field between conductors

Comment: How much heat you get is already there in your window :) in shape of the loss (all power that you put in but don't get out, ignoring leaking, is going to end up as heat). So, you take your material's specific heat capacity, invent a number for the maximum heating you want (hint: dielectric properties change with temperature, so you'll probably want to avoid getting 100 K hotter, even if the PCB substrate sustains that)

Comment: @Marcus Müller it's obviously. I can allow heat up around 50°C regarding to device body.

Comment: For the energy transport, you're mostly limited by the dielectric material (i.e., substrate) still being linear – meaning that you want to put in 20 % more voltage, you get a 20 % stronger E-field, and especially no arcing. Generally, that's rarely a curve you'll find in datasheets, but look at Volume resistivity and avoid getting any relevant

Comment: Is there any formulas that contains W, h, t, epsilon and Temp and give me Maximum RF power for strip line?

Comment: the ones I described? I'm not aware of anything more specific. If you need better than that, you'd directly go for FEM simulation, as maximum field strength is a limiting factor, and rule-of-thumbing it will either leave you overdimensioning by orders of magnitude, or risking catastrophic failure.

Comment: @Marcus Müller
"For the energy transport, you're mostly limited by the dielectric material". Are you sure about this statement? I can use same sub material, for example, RO4350. If I'll use it with standart height (0.762mm), than 50ohm line will be 1.75 mm wide. Probably it can transfer more energy? Or I'm mistaken?

Comment: the questions is how high is the electric field strength? Will you run into nonlinear, lossy, or even arcing troubles? So, you need to find the maximum E-field magnitude within your field, and that depends on the modes you're using and the geometry.